# fastest way to create cartesian product without duplicate elements inside pair

Tags: python, list, cartesian-product

I've list of indexes of images and it's length is 60000. I want to create another list which contains random pairs of indexes. The constraint here is each element of product set should contain distinct indexes. In other words I don't want to pair an index with it self.

Currently I've been using `itertools.product` method with `for` loop.

```
pairs = []
for pair in itertools.product(indexes, indexes):
    if pair[0]!=pair[1]:
        pairs.append(pair)
```

To problem it is taking a lot time and I couldn't use my computer because it gets stuck.

Is there better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it lazily without storing them:

```
pairs = filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1], itertools.product(indexes, indexes))
```

Use `itertools.ifilter` if using **`python2`**

The idea of using itertools is that you dont need to precompute everything but ask to compute it one item (computation) at a time.

I made a time comparition sugested by @Deepak Saini, that is [live here](https://repl.it/repls/WrithingPeachpuffTelephone):

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

indexes = np.arange(1000)

def pairs(indexes):
  pairs = []
  for pair in itertools.product(indexes, indexes):
      if pair[0]!=pair[1]:
          pairs.append(pair)
  return pairs

def iter_pairs(indexes):
  return filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1], itertools.product(indexes, indexes))

def iter_pairs_no_lambda(indexes):
  def comp(x):
    return x[0] != x[1]
  return filter(comp, itertools.product(indexes, indexes))

import time
for f in (pairs, iter_pairs, iter_pairs_no_lambda):
  print(f.__name__)
  t1 = time.time()
  res = f(indexes)
  print("Took {}".format(time.time() -  t1))
```

Which results on:

```
pairs
Took 1.012538194656372
iter_pairs
Took 0.04567384719848633
iter_pairs_no_lambda
Took 0.0002455711364746094
```

Comment: Hi, when I try on ``indexes = np.arange(1000)``,  doing a list() on the filter is slower than the OP's method. Can you explain that. Thanks.

Comment: The itertools.ifilter  is what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @DeepakSaini, probably is because of the use of the lambda or something related with `numpy`, try declaring a function and using that function instead of the lambda, times should improve.

Comment: @DeepakSaini,check the times in the updated answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray(indexes)
b = np.copy(a)

while np.any(a == b):
    b = np.random.choice(a, size=a.shape[0], replace=False)
```

And should be very fast

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have unique values, and then choose a combination of two of them.

```
list(itertools.combinations(set(indexes), 2))
```